# What are the names for the various Sobolev spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, terminology, sobolev-spaces

In conversation, how would one distinguish between the spaces $W^{k,p}$ and $W^{k,p}_0$? They're both "Sobolev spaces," but I can't find an actual name that distinguishes them.

Comment: I'd just pronounce all the super-/subscripts.

Comment: The second one can be described with "with zero boundary conditions" or "with homogeneous boundary conditions".

Comment: Most people do as @TZakrevskiy suggested. So "w-k-p-zero" vs "w-k-p".